# Host .NET Web Service that uses Oracle 10g DB

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, oracle10g

I am making a Web Service in .NET that will be consumed by android apps. The Database of my existing project is in Oracle 10g and is impossible to transfer to MSSql. The problem is that to connect to Oracle DB I need Oracle Client or atleast Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) which needs installation on machine. Now the problem is that I have yet not been able to find a Windows Hosting Server which has oracle client(All have MSSQL).

Can anyone tell me how to tackle this situation or if there is another way to do it or if there is any assembly available which i can directly refer in my project and connect to oracle db.

Comment: You probably need to find a Hosting Service that essentially rents you a virtual server that you can configure yourself. This is a lot more costly but necessary when you need to have special configurations.

Comment: How/where would you be hosting the actual database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` to get connected with Oracle Database  from your .net web service.

And you don't have install oracle one your machine to get connected with oracle from your application

Following [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/cook-dotnet-101788.html) may give some useful information to you

Comment: Doesn't it have any dependency?? Can I directly refer and use it.

Comment: Ya it doesn't have any dependency. You can directly refer  and use it